# Add slashes to json string in PHP

Tags: php

The (third-party) API I'm using is rather poorly documented. From a working example, I know that it accepts:

```
"{\"email\":\test@gmail.com\",\"something\":true,\"somethingelse\":[4,5],\"lastone\":false}"
```

My question is rather simple: how do I convert this:

```
"{email: test@gmail.com, something: true, somethingelse: [4,5], lastone: false}"
```

to the format above?

I've tried both `addslashes()` and `htmlspecialchars()` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

UPDATE:
To address the comments: well, I don't actually produce the second string, I just thought it was more convenient to ask the question this way (my bad). I only know the format that the API accepts, and I have values for $email, $something, $somethingelse and $lastone. So it's not necessary to convert the second string into the first one: a way to construct the first string based on the parameters would be even better :)

Comment: How do you make your string? Its not json

Comment: The string your trying to convert isn't valid JSON - it should have the corresponding quotes round the field names and string values.

Comment: How did you produce your other string? It's easier working with original data that a stringified example of it.

Comment: from where you are creating this line `"{email: test@gmail.com, something: true, somethingelse: [4,5], lastone: false}"
` can u plz share your code

Comment: \test@gmail.com\" or \"test@gmail.com\" ?

Comment: if \"test@gmail.com\" means why you can try with the str_replace()?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've updated my question with the relevant info.